# How to get token 2 onwards in BAT For

Tags: batch-file, cmd, token

The command `svn status` returns something like:

```
?       SomeClient\BUTCHERED.docx
M       SomeClient\Development notes.txt
?       SomeClient\Received\~$formation for prospective clients.docx
M       SomeClient\Sales\Estimates.xlsx
M       SomeClient\Sales\Specification.docx
?       SomeClient\Sales\~$Estimates.xlsx
?       SomeClient\Sales\~$ecification.docx
?       SomeClient\removed.docx
?       SomeClient\site spec1.docx
?       SomeClient\~$TCHERED.docx
?       SomeClient\~$emoved.docx
?       SomeClient\~$te spec1.docx
```

According to [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html), the first 5 columns are 1 character wide.

How can I output only the file names to a text file? This is what I have:

```
for /F "tokens=2*" %%U in ('svn status C:\SVN-EDGE') do echo %%U
```

But as soon as it hits a space in the file name, it stops echoing. If I change it to `do echo %%U %%V`, I get the correct output.

Is this the correct way to do it? I've been messing around with the tokens and delims for a while now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*` allocates a new variable.

map token 1 to `%%A` then just ignore it and use `%%B`

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%A in ('svn status C:\SVN-EDGE') do echo %%B
```

with `tokens=2*` `%%U` is matching token 2 and `%%V` is matching the `*`

---

If the first part is always the same length you can use a delayed substring to skip it: `!line:~8!`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('svn status C:\SVN-EDGE') do (
    set line=%%a
    set line=!line:~8!
    echo !line!
)
```

run `set /?` for more information on delayed expansion and variable manipulation.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks @William. For bonus points, any idea how to fix this 5x 1-character wide stuff?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I was using the sample input you supplied and I didn't notice.  You should be able to use delayed expansion and sub-strings.